# Receive data firebase error - android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Error message]

Code compiles ok - Problem is at showing data from server firebase

I need only one table from general table.

EXAMPLE:

Firebase database:

```
CLIENTE --> NAME: <--- ONLY SHOW THIS DATA
        TELEPHONE:
        etc...
```

CODE:

MainClass Show List Viewer.

```
public class ShowClienteFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<ShowCliente> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ShowCliente> mKeys = new ArrayList<>();

    private ListView newListView;

    private DatabaseReference gDatabase;



    public ShowClienteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_cliente, container, false);
       newListView = view.findViewById(R.id.lvCliente);
       final ArrayAdapter<ShowCliente> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
       newListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        gDatabase.child("cliente").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              ShowCliente show  = dataSnapshot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
              myList.add(show);
              //ShowCliente key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
              //mKeys.add(key);
              arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              //  String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
              //String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
              // int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);
              //  arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

         return view;
    }

}
```

Constructor Class

```
public class ShowCliente {


    private String razonsoc;

    public ShowCliente() {
    }

    public String getRazonsoc() {
        return razonsoc;
    }

    public void setRazonsoc(String razonsoc) {
        this.razonsoc = razonsoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've provided a possible answer below. If that isn't the problem, **edit** your question to include a sample of the actual JSON at `/cliente` (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

For each item from the database, you do this:

```
  ShowCliente show  = dataSnapshot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
  myList.add(show);
```

This means that you decode the `ShowCliente` from the JSON data and then add it to the list that your `ListView` shows. The `ListView` dutifully does what you tell it to do: it takes each `ShowCliente` object and displays it.

Since it doesn't know how to display a `ShowCliente`, it shows the `ShowCliente.toString()`, which by default shows a hashcode of the object.

You have two options to get the behavior you want:

1. Override `toString()` to return what you want. You do this by adding a `toString()` implementation to `ShowCliente`:

   ```
   public String toString() {
     return razonsoc.toString();
   }
   ```
2. Don't add the `ShowCliente` to the list, but just the value you want to display. To do this, change what you add to the list in `onChildAdded`:

   ```
   myList.add(show.getRazonsoc());
   ```

Comment: Apply the changes... and result!!, i need the String toString(){} to return the hashmap